# Saving images with the HTML Alt text description rather than the file

Tags: html, wget

I want to download a selection of images (about 300) from a supplier, I have used WGET to download the images and didn't have an issues, however, the files are numerically named and I want product names. I have checked the HTML console and there is a ALT text description. My question is:

can WGET recognised the ALT text and use that as the file name when downloading an image? If not what can?

Thank you in advance for your help